# SQL Table Appears Empty

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a bit new to MySQL and I am trying to create a search system. I am using some simple PHP code from w3schools.

I connect to my database:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "img";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Then echo the results.

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Description, Path FROM system";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"]. " " . $row["Description"]. " " . $row["Path"] . "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

My database contains one entry, but when I run this code, "0 Results" is echoed to the screen. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that as of MySQL 8, system is a reserved word, and path is a non-reserved keyword, whatever that means

Comment: Your code works fine in my test on MySQL 5.7. Maybe echo $conn->error before you close to see if your query is getting an error. What version of MySQL do you have?

Comment: Update: I did get this working, I had got my tables mixed up. Thanks!